# Setting up test server for current Website mamp dreamweaver local host

Tags: mysql, settings, dreamweaver

I am trying to load my website into dreamweaver, and mess around with it without altering my published page online. I transfered ALL files from my FTP to my desktop, Installed MAMP and Followed the setup and Set the site up in Dreamweaver. When I go to Preview my page I get the following error.

"J 5.5.33W(]!)Jv7ÿ÷€M[c^1w'Wclrymysql_native_password!ÿ„#08S01Got packets out of order"

My current settings are listed below:

MAMP Preferences
Apache Port: 80
MySQL Port:3306
Apache>Document Root="/Applications/MAMP/htdocs"

Dreamweaver testing server settings
Site Name: UFsite
Local Site Folder:"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/UFsite"
*servers setting*
Server Name: UFsite
Connect using: Local/Network
Server Folder: "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/UFsite"
WebURL: localhost:3306/htdocs/UFsite/""
Server Model: PHP MySQL

I can not figure out for the life of me... whats wrong...